# как создать процедуру, которая возвращает имя самого загруженного преподавателя?

Tags: sql-server

у меня есть две таблицы, в одной есть колонки препод и id препода, в другой предметы и id предметов, которые ведут преподы(если id препода и id предмета одинаковые, значит препод с таким id ведет предмет с этим id)
надо создать процедуру, которая возвращает имя препода, который ведет больше предметов чем другие преподы(каждый препод ведет разное количество преподов, то есть ситуации, когда есть два препода с одинаковым количеством предметов не будет)

```
USE Ten
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE FullNameOfTheTeacher
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM Disciplines
GROUP BY Discipline_ID
ORDER BY 1 DESC
END
GO
EXEC FullNameOfTheTeacher
```

этот вариант и близко не то что надо, но я ничего лучше не смог сделать

Comment: Ну вопрос первый - как вообще посчитать загрузку... ответ вроде очевиден - просуммировать (не посчитать!) часы. Второй вопрос - считать надо для преподавателя, значит группировать надо по преподавателям, а не по часам... Ну и третий вопрос - когда по каждому препу известна сумма его часов, как найти самого загруженного? ну, видимо, просто отсортировать по убыванию, и взять самого первого.

Comment: у меня нету колчичество часов, id предметов или id преподов это не количество часов которое они преподают, к примеру есть таблица 
Яковлев   2
Кравцов  5
и еще таблилца 
Дискретная математика 2
Физика                             3
Кобинаторика                 2
тогда самый загруженый яковлев, поскольку он ведет два предмета

Comment: Ну мало что поменялось - изменится только пункт 2, с учётом объяснений использование COUNT() корректно.

Comment: `select top 1 ... from .. inner join ... group by ... order by count(..) ...`   заполнить пропуски